# How to turn on tick labels on matplotlib subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to turn on the tick labels on all of the 9 subplots using this piece of code:

```
for ax in plt.gcf().get_axes():
    for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
        label.set_visible(True)
```

The code does not show any error message when executed. But the image was unchanged and tick labels were still invisible. I have tried redrawing the figure using canvas.draw(). But this does not help as well.

The subplots were created using :

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6), (ax7, ax8, ax9)) = plt.subplots(3, 3 , sharex = True, sharey = True)
```

Note: I am using %matplotlib notebook as the backend.

I have included a picture of the subplots below.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for cAx in ax.flatten():
        cAx.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)
        cAx.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

[image]

You can read more about this particular issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10911/)

Comment: My figure still looks cramped. I used the plt.tight_layout(). But still yours looks better. How did you manage the size and spaces of the subplots so efficiently ?

Comment: You can either make the figure larger using `fig.set_size_inches(width, height)` or you can adjust the spacing between subplots using `plt.subplots_adjust()`